# node js express path not functioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));

var dirname = __dirname;
app.get("/:lang/:app",function(req,res){
  console.log(req.params.lang + " " + req.params.app);
  res.sendFile(dirname + "/index.html", { layout: false });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3001,function(){
  console.log("started");
});
```

this is my code for index.js when I use only get("/") it shows ok, but when I do what I did there it doesn't load the html or css and gives this error:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\directory\calculator-release\index.html'
what can I do to fix it?

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));

var dirname = __dirname;
app.get("/",function(req,res){
  //console.log(req.params.lang + " " + req.params.app);
  res.sendFile(dirname + "/index.html", { layout: false });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3001,function(){
  console.log("started");
});
```

This code works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Like the error message said, the path seems be wrong where you tried to return the html file

Edit: __dirname is your current workdirectory. So instead of `dirname + "/index.html"` you could try `dirname + "/public/index.html"`

Comment: But it works with app.get("/",function(req,res){ and not with app.get("/:lang/:app",function(req,res){...

Comment: app.use(express.static("public")); I use this but it doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: Could you edit your main post and post the function where are you trying with "/" as route? Just to make sure, thats its identical

Comment: i updated my post which shows why static does nothing

Comment: This half works, it works with app.get("/:lang",function(req,res){ but not with app.get("/:lang/:app",function(req,res){, for some reason iwth "/:lang/:app" it doesn't find the files, and tells me it couldn't find them in dirname/:app

Comment: I think I understand what happened, when I type this: http://localhost:3001/en/app, and tell it to do this: console.log(req.params.lang + " " + req.params.app); it prints:
en app
en styles.css
en calc.js
en sw.js
en manifest.json
which means it tries to load http://localhost:3001/en/styles.css, how can I tell him to take this from public and not en?

Comment: do you have any ideas?